# React JS MUI Datepicker strange red border

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datepicker

In my reactJS app, I've setted up some datepicker and everything works good.

In a custom page, i have another datepicker and i see a strange red border around it:

[image]

The code is:

```
<DatePicker
        disableFuture
        style={{ width: "90%", border: "1px solid black" }}
        inputFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField fullWidth {...params} />}
        value={props.value}
        fullWidth
        onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
        onChange={(e) =>
          props.handleChangeComponentValue(props.id, e.target.value)
        }
        onBlur={(e) => props.handleBlurComponent(props.id, e.target.value)}
      />
```

inspecting it with chrome i see that the style comes from

```
<fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="sc-gKseQn jzeLFY MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline-SmBCs dwFpjw MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline">
    <legend class="sc-iBPTik gOBiIn">
        <span class="notranslate">&ZeroWidthSpace;</span>
    </legend>
</fieldset>
```

in particular:

```
.hiztcv.Mui-error .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: #f44336;
}
```

I'm not setting any class of it, and that color is not set in my project.

Did i miss something?

Comment: If you pick a date, does it disappear? Seems like an error class is being applied to it by something, maybe that could be the default empty value? Is `props.value` a valid date? Have you tried using `defaultValue` instead?

Comment: @ConorReid that's a valid point. I cannot pick a date because I'm working on the login behind it. I'll try it. Anyway I need to use value because is a controlled component (If I understood it correctly)

Comment: @ConorReid you were right. After setting `value={props.value || null}` the border is disappeared. thanks!

Comment: All good! Glad I could provide some help.

Answer (score 7):

To fix this issue we can apply slotProps in the Date picker component.

Visit https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
  <DatePicker
    slotProps={{
      textField: {
        size: "small"
        error: false,
      },
    }}
    value={value || dayjs(field.value)}
    onChange={field.onChange}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>;
```

Comment: Actually this is completely wrong and this causes another problem instead https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/10274 , I found the proper soluton, will post the answer below

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue. When I console.log params coming to the renderInput property, I saw that it has the default property of error:true.

So you can fix it like this:

```
<DatePicker
    ...
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} error={false} />}
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same case and the problem was in the initial value of the date. It was an empty string and DatePicker interpreted it as an invalid date, so I changed the initial value to `undefined`, and now it has today's date as default and doesn't has an error state.

Comment: This corrected it for me and seems like the more appropriate way to address the issue than the other answers. The other answers rely on styling or overriding the the error state.

Comment: Pass null instead of undefined. It will show you an empty date picker field.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avnW4.png)

This behaviour is seen when you are using two material UI data-picker components simultaneous in a single page.There are two ways of  solving this
one is overriding the css
other is by setting the default value of error={false}
1.Overriding the css

```
<div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary Mui-error MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-adornedEnd css-1bn53lx"><input aria-invalid="true" id=":r1m:" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" type="tel" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd css-1uvydh2" value=""><div class="MuiInputAdornment-root MuiInputAdornment-positionEnd MuiInputAdornment-outlined MuiInputAdornment-sizeMedium css-1nvf7g0"><button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-edgeEnd MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-slyssw" tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Choose date"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-vubbuv" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="CalendarIcon"><path d="M17 12h-5v5h5v-5zM16 1v2H8V1H6v2H5c-1.11 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L3 19c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-1V1h-2zm3 18H5V8h14v11z"></path></svg><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span></button></div><fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline css-igs3ac"><legend class="css-ihdtdm"><span class="notranslate">​</span></legend></fieldset></div>
```

The above code has Mui-error class which is responsible for show that red line. You can try overriding that.

1. Do pass error={false} by default where you are using renderInput component after params

> <DatePicker
> ...
> renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} error={false} />}
> ... />

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the initial value should NOT be an empty string but instead `null`, see info from author https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/10274

The currently most upvoted solution causes the issue that the date is always considered valid even if a user hasn't filled in any date...

Comment: There is no accepted answer. See comments below question and you'll find the same solution you've proposed