# MUI datepicker how can i remove red border which is displaying

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI datepicker here and when I use this before entering any value I see red border after selecting the date it disappears.

[Here is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeIEj.png)

```
 const [selectDate, setSelectDate] = useState("");

  const handleDate = (newValue) => {
    setSelectDate(newValue);
  };
      
 <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <DesktopDatePicker
                    // label="Date desktop"

                    inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
                    value={selectDate}
                    onChange={handleDate}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField  error={false} fullWidth {...params}  />
                    )}
                  />
                </LocalizationProvider>
```

Here I tried giving error false but it does not dissappear anyone have gone through this issue  if yes then how can i fix it..

Comment: Have you tried `overwriting` the `CSS` rules which cause the red border to appear? Try applying the `hover`, `focus` effects via the `devtools` and see which one causes the red line to appear, then find the `CSS` code which sets the red border and overwrite it with `!important` in your `CSS`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React JS MUI Datepicker strange red border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71326837/react-js-mui-datepicker-strange-red-border)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` in `renderInput` prop override your definition of the  `TextField`s' `error` prop because the `{...params}` prop is defined after it (there is an additional `error` prop inside the `params` bundle).

If you define the `error` prop after, you will override the `renderInput`s' error prop and the red line will disappear.

```js
<TextField fullWidth {...params} error={false} />
```

By default the parameter props passed by the `renderInput` consider an error if no date value is selected, value is empty, or the date format for value is wrong.